# Is there a way to use the same objects for two connected services at different endpoints?

Tags: vb.net, web-services, soap

I am new to Visual Basic and setting up services in Visual Studio. Right now, I have two service references with two different WSDL files, but they are the same web service. The only difference is that one is our QA endpoint and the other is our production endpoint. Is there a way to set things up such that they both share the same request and response classes, or do I need to duplicate code when calling these services?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out there's an `<endpoints>` section in my project's app.config file that does exactly what I want here. I just needed to add another endpoint with a different name and the same contract. Yay!